# Как скрыть все div-ы у которых data-name-ы не совпадают со списком?

Tags: javascript

Как объяснить проще не знаю, расскажу по порядку.

1. Я сделал функцию за счет которой можно добавлять в `localStorage`, `data-name`-ы `div`-ов
2. После того как я покликал по нужным дивам, в `localStorage` образовался такой список `divnomer1 || divnomer2 || divnomer5`
3. Как скрыть все `div`-ы у которых `data-name`-ы не совпадают со списком?
   допустим `divnomer3` и `divnomer4`

Comment: та строка со списком, в таком виде и хранится у тебя в `localStorage?`

Comment: да, `data-name`-ы делятся между собой по ||, могу поменять разделитель на любой другой символ

Comment: нужно выбрать все дивы у которых name не совпадает, пробежаться по ним и выставить соответствующий класс/стиль который их скроет

Comment: @SloGS если это придумали вы, то вы придумали плохо. Просто нужно имена складывать в массив имен и потом парсить в JSON. А когда нужно доставать строку, парсить и пробежаться по дереву проверяя есть ли `whiteList.indexOf(<текущийатрибутдомэлемента>)`

Comment: Складывать имена каждого `div`a и парсить их в json и потом пробегатся по дереву и проверять на наличие совпадений? А как вы предлагаете продумать данную функцию, просто проще я придумать не смог, я начинающий

Comment: @SloGS `JSON.parse(строка)` и `JSON.stringify(массив)`

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев, лучше объект, а не массив, чтобы искалось быстрее при проверке

Comment: @Grundy ну можно и объект, но в таких случаях я больше использую именно массивы. Ну да если использовать объект можно проверять не `indexOf()`, а на `=== undefined`. Так то даже 1000 элементов он обработает где то за секунду (а то и меньше), ты даже не заметишь)

Comment: Ваши наводки меня не к чему не привели, пойду в просторы гугла, если разберусь напишу,

я не понял таки как их скрывать проверяя массив =D

Comment: @SloGS я ответ уже опубликовал

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как пример:

```js
// Где-то вы заполнили массив (array.push('имя'))
// Далее вы закинули в localStorage.setItem('nameList', JSON.stringify(array));
// тут должен быть JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('nameList'));
var array = ['name1', 'name5', 'name7']; // << вот тут вместо ручного массива
var nameList = document.querySelectorAll('.dataDiv');

var i = nameList.length;
while (i--) {
  var attrName = nameList[i].getAttribute('data-name');

  if (array.indexOf(attrName) === -1) {
    nameList[i].style.display = 'none';
    console.log(attrName + ' был скрыт'); 
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="dataDiv" data-name="name1">name1</div>
<div class="dataDiv" data-name="name2">name2</div>
<div class="dataDiv" data-name="name3">name3</div>
<div class="dataDiv" data-name="name4">name4</div>
<div class="dataDiv" data-name="name5">name5</div>
<div class="dataDiv" data-name="name6">name6</div>
<div class="dataDiv" data-name="name7">name7</div>
```

А вот проверка выполнения с 1000 генерируемых элементов:

```js
var i = 1000;
var rootDiv = document.getElementById('myDivs');
while (i--) {
  var el = document.createElement('div');
  el.classList.add('dataDiv');
  el.setAttribute('data-name', 'name' + i);
  el.innerText = 'name' + i;
  rootDiv.insertBefore(el, rootDiv.children[0]);
}

// тут должен быть JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('nameList'));
var array = ['name1', 'name5', 'name7']; 
var nameList = document.querySelectorAll('.dataDiv');

var i = nameList.length;
console.time('time');
while (i--) {
  var attrName = nameList[i].getAttribute('data-name');

  if (array.indexOf(attrName) === -1) {
    nameList[i].style.display = 'none';
  }
}
console.timeEnd('time');
```

```html
<div id="myDivs"></div>
```

Comment: Помоему я вас понял, сейчас проверю у себя

Comment: Как пробежаться по `div`-ам? добавляя их `data-name`-ы в массив? у меня не получается(

Comment: @SloGS, пример прохода по выбранным дивам можете увидеть в ответе: цикл while

Comment: @SloGS Я добавил ещё один пример с генерируемыми дивами, нужно просто от туда взять код с `setAttribute` и бегать по дом дереву как в первом случае

Comment: При `var izbrannye = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("favorites"));` выдает ошибку, может потому что в `data-name`-ах есть символы ()?
_SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON data at line 1 column 5 of the JSON data_

Comment: @SloGS что возвращает `localStorage.getItem("favorites")`?

Comment: Все я решил проблему спасибо больше, там и парсить не пришлось ответ от localStorage

Comment: @SloGS и как решили? localStorage может хранить только строки

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев парсить строгу `LocalStorage` даже не нужно было, работает и так, в переменную `array` прописал `localStorage` сразу

Comment: @SloGS там строка, если когда то будешь записывать туда данные типа `.setItem('myVal', [1,2,3,4, {a:5, b:7}])`, тебе будет возвращаться `.getItem('myVal')` -> `"1,2,3,4,[object Object]"`. Всегда приводи к нужным типам, т.е. парсь в строку JSON, так ты будешь 100% уверен, что будут возвращаться конкретные данные

Comment: Спасибо большое, буду знать на будущее

Answer (score 2):

В дополнение к соседнему ответу: проверку можно перенести на браузер и убрать `if` если использовать селектор [`:not`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/:not)

```js
// Где-то вы заполнили массив (array.push('имя'))
// Далее вы закинули в localStorage.setItem('nameList', JSON.stringify(array));
// тут должен быть JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('nameList'));
var array = ['name1', 'name5', 'name7']; // << вот тут вместо ручного массива

var nameList = document.querySelectorAll('.dataDiv' + array.map(el => `:not([data-name="${el}"])`).join(''));

var i = nameList.length;
while (i--) {
  var attrName = nameList[i].getAttribute('data-name');
  nameList[i].style.display = 'none';
  console.log(attrName + ' был скрыт');
}
```

```html
<div class="dataDiv" data-name="name1">name1</div>
<div class="dataDiv" data-name="name2">name2</div>
<div class="dataDiv" data-name="name3">name3</div>
<div class="dataDiv" data-name="name4">name4</div>
<div class="dataDiv" data-name="name5">name5</div>
<div class="dataDiv" data-name="name6">name6</div>
<div class="dataDiv" data-name="name7">name7</div>
```

```js
var i = 1000;
var rootDiv = document.getElementById('myDivs');
while (i--) {
  var el = document.createElement('div');
  el.classList.add('dataDiv');
  el.setAttribute('data-name', 'name' + i);
  el.innerText = 'name' + i;
  rootDiv.insertBefore(el, rootDiv.children[0]);
}

// тут должен быть JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('nameList'));
var array = ['name1', 'name5', 'name7'];

function check1(array) {
  var nameList = document.querySelectorAll('.dataDiv');

  var i = nameList.length;
  console.time('time');
  while (i--) {
    var attrName = nameList[i].getAttribute('data-name');

    if (array.indexOf(attrName) === -1) {
      nameList[i].style.display = 'none';
    }
  }
  console.timeEnd('time');
}

function check2(array) {
  var nameList = document.querySelectorAll('.dataDiv' + array.map(el => `:not([data-name="${el}"])`).join(''));

  var i = nameList.length;
  console.time('time');
  while (i--) {
    var attrName = nameList[i].getAttribute('data-name');
    nameList[i].style.display = 'none';
  }
  console.timeEnd('time');
}

console.log('with if');
check1(array);
console.log('without if');
check2(array);
```

```html
<div id="myDivs"></div>
```

Comment: Посмотрел сколько по времени выполняется, почему то долго, 366+ мс для 1000 элементов

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев, не совсем понял, у меня без if, показывает выигрыш в два раза, за счет того что `indexOf` убрался, хотя он тут совсем мелкий и не должен был повлиять, возможно от браузеров зависит

Comment: Хм, а вот, это все злой `console.log` :)) да отличный вариант

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев, забавно, в EDGE, с `if` быстрее чуть, в хроме быстрее `без if` - в два раза, в firefox - `без if` быстрее почти в 3 раза

Comment: edge как и вся его линейка знать не знают как работать с dom (видимо), поэтому js выполняется быстрее. А в нормальных браузерах  стандартные средства (селекторы) лучше (быстрее) работают

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев, засекалась-то не выборка, в цикле же пробег по уже выбранным элементам.

Comment: Т.е. можно с уверенностью сказать, что `javascript` Egde поддерживает лучше остальных браузеров (в плане скорости)?)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40369/discussion-between-grundy-and--).

Comment: все спасибо большое, вы в двоём очень помогли, почему нельзя выбрать два правильных овтета